# Uncaught Exception while building a timer

Tags: ios, uncaught-exception

I keep getting a SIGABRT error because of an uncaught exception:

```
  2016-02-11 01:54:23.232 time_01[1937:52731] -[time_01.ViewController increaseTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf72d12c20
2016-02-11 01:54:23.235 time_01[1937:52731] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[time_01.ViewController increaseTime]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf72d12c20'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6adf45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001103d1deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6b656d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e603eea ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e603a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010ea93181 __NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e60e264 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e60de11 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5cf821 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5cee08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112ca1ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010eeca30d UIApplicationMain + 171
    12  time_01                             0x000000010e4d140d main + 109
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110ed992d start + 1
    14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I looked through my code for the simple timer and I can't figure out how to change the code so it doesn't return an error.

```
var timer = NSTimer()

var time = 0

@IBOutlet var timeText: UILabel!

func increaseTimer() {

        time = time + 1

        timeText.text = "\(time)"

}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("increaseTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Selector("increaseTime")` vs `Selector("increaseTimer")` since your method is named `func increaseTimer() {}`

Answer (score 1):

It is because your function name is `func increaseTimer()` and when setting selector you are setting `selector: Selector("increaseTime")`.

So to solve your problem, either rename your method:

```
func increaseTime() {

        time = time + 1

        timeText.text = "\(time)"

}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("increaseTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Or update your method name at time you set the selector:

```
func increaseTimer() {

        time = time + 1

        timeText.text = "\(time)"

}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("increaseTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

The most significant part of the crash message is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-**[time_01.ViewController
>   increaseTime]: unrecognized selector sent** to instance 0x7fdf72d12c20'

Your timer sends a selector `increaseTime` but there is no property or method with this name.

Programming is a very precise business. A missing character or case mismatch can break the whole system.

You have to ensure that the signature of the method and the selector match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using in one of my project and it's working fine.

Here is the timer:

> self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self,
>   selector: "startQuestionTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

And here is the method:

```
  func startQuestionTimer(obj:NSTimer){
  }
```

This should work for sure.

Comment: The passed argument is not mandatory but could be helpful in case of `NSTimer`